# Finding gcd of two unknowns included in this linear diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

Given that a,b are integers such that $2a+3b=6$, I'm trying to prove:

i) $\frac{a}{3},\frac{b}{2}$ are integers

ii) gcd($\frac{a}{3},\frac{b}{2}$)=1

I know that, the solution of this linear diophantine equation is $a = -6 + 3n$ and $b = 6 - 2n$ where n is an integer.

From the solutions I can write:

$$\frac{a}{3}=-2+n\\\frac{b}{2}=3-n$$

Since n is an integer i) is proven. However, I have no idea how to move on with the second proof

Comment: i) follows immediately from the equation, e.g. $\,3b=6-2a$ is even so $b$ is even. For ii) divide the equation by $6\ \ $

Comment: Why does the division by 6 help?

Comment: You'll get $\,a/3 + b/2 = 1\,$ so $\,a/3,\,b/2\,$  are coprime - since any common divisor also divides their sum $= 1;\,$ or view it as their gcd Bezout equation.

Comment: Strangely Hagen's answer didn't appear till after I typed the prior comment. It is essentially the same as I explain above (just so you know that I didn't mean to imply it was different - I simply hadn't seen it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$ 1=\frac{2a+3b}6=\frac a3+\frac b2$$
is a multiple of $\gcd(\frac a3,\frac b2)$.